# AngularJS and Browserify: Including services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, browserify, require

I've got an interesting question I can't seem to wrap my head around. Perhaps one of you can help me here as I'm not sure I'm doing anything right at the moment..

I'm trying to set up modular loading on my little framework/boilerplate.

I have a main **app.js** file:

```
var angular = require('angular');
require('angular-route');

require('./services/socketService');

var app = angular.module('universe', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','socketService']);

app.config(require('./options/routes'));
```

The **options/routes.js**:

```
var fs = require('fs');
module.exports = function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller: require('../controllers/main.js'),
      template: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../views/main.html')
    })
    .when('/page2', {
      controller: require('../controllers/page2.js'),
      template: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../views/page2.html')
    });
};
```

The **services/socketServices.js** file:

```
'use strict';

require('angular');

angular.module('socketService').factory('socketService', function () {

    console.log('service loaded');

});

module.exports = socketService;
```

I keep getting the error...

```
[$injector:nomod] Module 'socketService' is not available!
```

As far as I can tell, the socketService should be loaded.. but it isn't. The controllers themselves load fine, as they're only module.export functions because of the way they're included. What am I missing here? How do I add services and directives?

Please.. help. :)

Kind regs,

sn0r.

Comment: Typo: `module.exports = socketService`

Comment: Yeah.. I saw that. Thanks :) Still doesn't work though; same error really.

Comment: Remove `require('angular');` from your service file. If that fixes the issue, I'll give an explanation.